# glTexImage2D copies data or just specifies it?

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

```
  InitTexture (  ) {
int size = 600 * 600 * 4;
float text[ 600 * 600 * 4 ];
glGenTextures ( 1, &texture_ );

glBindTexture ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_ );
for ( int i = 0 ; i < size ;  ) {
    text[ i ] = 0.5f;
    text[ i + 1 ] = 0.0f;
    text[ i + 2 ] = 0.0f;
    text[ i + 3 ] = 1.0f;
    i += 4;
}
glTexImage2D ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 600, 600, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, text
    );
glBindTexture ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0 );
Renderable::IsGLError ( "InitTexture: GL Error occured ..... " );
 }
```

The application with this texture initialization fails.

```
 int size = 600 * 600 * 4;     // global
 float text[ 600 * 600 * 4 ];  // global

 InitTexture (  ) {
glGenTextures ( 1, &texture_ );

glBindTexture ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_ );
for ( int i = 0 ; i < size ;  ) {
    text[ i ] = 0.5f;
    text[ i + 1 ] = 0.0f;
    text[ i + 2 ] = 0.0f;
    text[ i + 3 ] = 1.0f;
    i += 4;
}
glTexImage2D ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 600, 600, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, text
    );
glBindTexture ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0 );
 Renderable::IsGLError ( "InitTexture: GL Error occured ..... " );
 }
```

But when text array is a global pointer it is work as it should. What does it mean? glTexImage2D does not copy the data, does it?

Comment: What is your question? Do you get any error messages saying that something went wrong? Normally, `glTexImage2D()` will copy the data up to the video card. But if there's an error, then it probably didn't.

Comment: Perhaps it's your texture side length.  It's not a power of 2.  Try make it a power of 2, and see if it works.

Comment: I made it 1024 x 1024. The same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

glTexImage2D always makes a copy of the data. If there's an error then it has another reason than the whereabouts of the source data buffer.

Comment: @user14416: glGetError is a peculiar thing; it doesn't suffice to call it only once, as errors accumulate. You must call glGetError is a loop until GL_NO_ERROR it returned. Also you should check for errors not only after doing OpenGL calls but also before to make sure you're operating on a clean state.